Property value of WinForm not being set
Here's the scenario:
I have a checkbox that when the form is initialized the Visible property of this checkbox is set to false.
Then, during the program execution, the Visible property is set to true and the program continues on its merry way.
However, even though the checkbox IS visible when the form is shown, IMMEDIATELY after setting the property, its value does not change.
I posted a video here to demonstrate it during debug.
Has anyone seen this?
It's the first time I see something remotely close to this happening.
This is the code executed:
1 | Using frm As New FormLicenseInput(Me, code, product)
2 |    frm.Message = msg
3 |    frm.CheckDontShow.Visible = _IsInitializing
4 |    If frm.OpenDialog(ownerWindow) = DialogResult.Cancel Then
5 |        Return Nothing
6 |    End If
7 | End Using

The property is changed on line 3, but on line 4, when checking during debug, its value is not changed.

According to this C# answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/11161477/880990, the Visible property is set correctly internally but will display False as long as the Form itself has Visible = False, which is the case since it has not yet been opened.

The handle of the Control has not been created yet, the new value is cached in the State bits. The Layout transaction will consider it after

Thanks... It's been a while since I worked with WinForms. (I used to know this obscure bits of information).

Make the value of message and the Boolean for visibility as parameters to the Form's constructor, and set the values in there.

Thanks to Olivier Jacot-Descombes and Jimi for pointing to the solution.
As long as the form's handle (and the control's handle) has no being created the property, in this case the Visible property, is stored only internally and not available to the outside.
(Pretty weird design solution if you ask me.)

Not weird at all. You always have to consider that a good part of the WinForms Controls are actually Win32 Controls. The .NET object is often just a wrapper that adds useful Properties and Methods (and handles the construction of the Win32 window). The Win32 Controls operate through Win32 API, and all these require a Handle. So, setting actual properties of the real Control when the a Handle is not available, may (will) cause cascading events, effects and API calls that cannot work correctly, bound to generate unhandled exceptions

.NET Controls that don't derived from Win32 Controls (e.g., DataGridView), and Components that require a message queue (e.g., the Timer) also have a backing Win32 window, constructed through a NativeWindow object. A Handle is still required to operate. The Handle is created after the object's construction and before the Layout transaction (when a Control's Layout is performed). This is signaled by the OnHandleCreated() method
